# Set asp:Image Url When image is uploaded in asp:FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How can I show the image in asp:Image control after the image is selected in asp:FileUpload Control without any Button Click ?

Here is my Code :

```
   <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_edu" Width="100" Height="100" />
   <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileupload_edu" />
```

I've gone through many links but got no idea because i don't want any button click.

I've also seen :http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/933229/Upload-image-using-FileUpload-and-display-in-Image-control-in-ASPNet/ but same problem i.e. button click .

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using javascript.

```
 <script>
    function img() {
        var url = inputToURL(document.getElementById("<%=fileupload_edu.ClientID %>"));
        document.getElementById("<%=img_edu.ClientID %>").src = url;
    }
    function inputToURL(inputElement) {
        var file = inputElement.files[0];
        return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
</script>
```

You Controls

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_edu" Width="100" Height="100" />
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileupload_edu" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="img();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call change event.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= fileupload_edu.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#<%= img_edu.ClientID%>").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", e.target.result).fadeIn();
                })
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need an onchange event to detect when the file is loaded

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_edu" Width="100" Height="100" />
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" onchange="LoadImg()" ID="fileupload_edu" />
```

Then use this function to show the selected file

```
    function loadImg(element) {
      var tgt = element.target || window.event.srcElement, files = tgt.files;

      if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function () {
          document.getElementById("<%=img_edu.ClientID%>").src = fr.result;
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      }
      else {

      }
   }
```